# Java Swing How can I accomplish a navigator like in the example

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, navigator

For my current project I would like to have a navigator like this:

[image]

But I couldn't find a Swing component that works like that.
My question now is, does anyone know how to do this and could explain it to me or give me a tip?

Comment: Thanks. I only needed the JTree tip. Im really glad that you answered that quickly and thanks for the rating of my question. Next time I'll make it better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Along the top is a tool bar (`JToolBar`). On the left is a tabbed pane (`JTabbedPane`) showing a tree (`JTree`) in the current tab. On the right is a tree table (I would say `JTable`, but it is a pure table, not a tree table - you might need to look to 3rd party APIs for that part).

More generally, see:

- [A Visual Guide to Swing Components](http://da2i.univ-lille1.fr/doc/tutorial-java/ui/features/components.html)
- The [File Browser GUI](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) for both a `JTree` for the file-system on the left, & using the native/system Look and Feel (to make it look more like the image above).
  [image]